# AwesomeWM, Proper Configuration with Multiple Monitors - Cloning, Activating Additional Monitors without Logging out, vertical display, monitor order

Tags: display, window-manager, awesome

I have four related questions regarding the use of the window manager AwesomeWM when multiple monitors are involved. These are all fairly simple configuration questions, but I have not been able to figure them out.

1: If I am already in Awesome-WM, and I plug in an additional monitor, Awesome cannot figure out that there is an additional monitor and create a new desktop image and visuals on it. I have to log out and log back in again, and even resetting with ctrl-super-r does not suffice. This also applies in reverse - if I launch Awesome with two monitors, removing one results in Awesome still thinking there is another monitor and having windows there, the mouse going over the edge, etc. How can I resolve this without logging out and back in?

2: I may wish to clone the display to two or more screens, if I am doing a presentation. Awesome defaults to a new desktop with its own items on it. I have found no setting that changes this.

3: If one of the monitors is a vertical monitor, it is of course desired for Awesome to change its alignment to vertical, shifting things by 90 degrees and changing what the "top" is. Instead, it thinks the monitor is still in the typical, "standard" layout, and I have found no setting to change this.

4: When using three monitors, Awesome-WM currently thinks that the monitor in the center is monitor 1, the monitor to the right is monitor 2, and the monitor to the left is monitor 3. This results in moving the mouse to the right or using shortcut keys to go to the next to the right monitor, and it jumping over to the leftmost monitor, which is awkward. I would like to change the order but have found no setting to do so.

What are the configurations needed to make AwesomeWM work with multiple monitors in these ways?